# Why doesn't the compiler recognize the -URLForResource:withExtension method on NSBundle?

Tags: iphone

I downloaded the code for Apple's [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.htm) sample application, but I am unable to compile this application.  It's showing a warning for this line

```
NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestPage.pdf" withExtension:nil];

NSBundle may not respond to URLForResource:withExtension
```

I build using the iPhone OS 3.2.1 SDK.  Why is it giving me this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URLForResource:withExtension:` method is available starting SDK 4.0. In older systems you need to use other methods, e.g. obtain path to the resource file using `pathForResource:ofType:` method first and then convert it to NSURL

Comment: Bro could you help me more,this sample code works for only one page,but what if i want to read a pdf document or book in iphone.I uploaded the book to the bundel but it shows the first page.How to scroll to different pages.Pease give me the solution

Comment: You can get arbitrary pdf page with CGPDFDocumentGetPage function - search that sample to see how it is used to set view contents.